# How to run several tests with one Firefox instance, Selenium WebDriver with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-unittest, class-method

I'm learning to write automatic tests using Selenium WebDriver with Python. I have couple of tests in `WidgetArea` class, I would like to run them all in one instance of Firefox, I know that I need to specify `setUp` and `tearDown` as `@classmethod` but I do not know what else should I change to achieve that goal? Code can be found below:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class WidgetArea(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUp(cls):

    # create new firefox session
    cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()
    # navigate to aplication page
    cls.driver.get("http://demoqa.com/")
    cls.driver.title

def test_widget_area(self):

    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/aside")
    self.assertEqual(4, len(elements))

def test_widget_list(self):

    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@id='menu-widget']/li")
    self.assertEqual(7, len(elements))

def test_interaction(self):

    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@id='menu-interactions']/li")
    self.assertEqual(5, len(elements))

@classmethod
def tearDown(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to perform automated tests using `selenium` as `unittests`. You can build your own framework and adjust it just like you want

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to automatic tests in general, and alos in OOP Languages so I wolud like to start with something easy for the start and unittest seams to be good choice. I think I'm far form starting writing my own automatic framework as far as my knowledge goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `unittests` with `selenium`, so I can advise tests in specific framework which you can adjust and update as you like despite of `unittests` rules:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class WidgetArea():

  def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.get("http://demoqa.com/")

  def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

  def widget_area(self):
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='secondary']/aside")
    try:
        assert len(elements) == 4
        print("Test pass")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Assertion failed")

  def widget_list(self):
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@id='menu-widget']/li")
    try:
        assert len(elements) == 7
        print("Test pass")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Assertion failed")

  def interaction(self):
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@id='menu-interactions']/li")
    try:
        assert len(elements) == 5
        print("Test pass")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Assertion failed")

  def main(self):
    self.setUp()
    self.widget_area()
    self.widget_list()
    self.interaction()
    self.tearDown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = WidgetArea()
    new.main()
```

All assertions will be performed during single browser session.

Comment: If this was useful, please make a +1 Upvote for this answer, if this resolved your issue please accept it with check under answer rate, if this doesn't works, tell me what should be improved

Comment: HI, @Andersson, +1Upvote, I'm just to low level in reputation to make it display, and I accepted as an answer. Thank You a lot, best regards